# Modal Popup Not Displaying inside Iframe in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, modal-dialog

I have created a PHP web application using twitter bootstrap and jquery. This application is inside an iframe on our website here: http://southcommdigital.com/admin/ . When you click on the login link on the top right, a modal pops up with a login form. This works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but the modal won't display in Internet Explorer. Additionally, this WILL work in IE if you browse to the iframe page itself here: http://omgsurvey.com/apps/Dan/index.php . Is this a known issue and does anybody know of a workaround for this? Thank you for any help you can give me.

Trigger Link:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#loginModal">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> </span>&nbsp;Login
</a>
```

Popup code:

```
<div class="modal fade text-center" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width: 400px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h1 class="modal-title">Login</h1>
      </div>
      <form role="form" name="loginformname" method="post" id="loginformname" class="loginformid" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="form_action.php">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
                <div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                <div>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <input name="action" id="action" value="login" type="hidden">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <input name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
      </form> 
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->      <!-- END LOGIN MODAL  -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version you have you can check out the console in IE (F12), it looks like you have some errors that may need to be settled.

Comment: It appears that Internet Explorer is not allowing access to the script for jquery being called inside of the iframe. Is this a cross-domain javascript/iframe issue?

Comment: Is it possible that you might be running something before jQuery is referenced?

Comment: Well i get "Access Denied" for the jquery script and then things like jQuery is undefined" after that. This seems to all be tied to first jquery script call:     `<script src="http://omgsurvey.com/apps/Dan/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`